# Make cookie consent manager mandatory

Tags: php, cookies, shopware6

can the shopware cookie consent manager be made mandatory?
That means that the customer must accept or deny cookies before entering the shop.
Is there a switch for it or has it to be developed as decorated service like explained here https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-cookie-to-manager#extend-the-cookie-consent-manager ?

Or should it be easier to use an external consent manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by javascript https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/reacting-to-cookie-consent-changes. For example, you can make up the cookie contest in popup and listen on cookie changes to hide or keep the popup.